# Matplotlib Plot showing image as separate r g b images rather than a single RGB image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an image represented as a Numpy Array of shape [224, 224, 3]. i am trying to plot this using matplotlib using:
        plt.imshow(img)
But instead of getting a single RGB image, it plots the separated R, G and B images in a single plot. Where am I going wrong?

I have tried looking at the shape of the image and also some examples to plot the image. The "img" variable has the shape of [224, 224, 3] and is a numpy array type.

```
        from torchvision import datasets, transforms
        from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


        # Define Image Transform
        transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])

        # Load Custom Image Dataset
        dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root="./Cat_Dog_data", 
                                          transform=transform)

        # DataLoader
        dataLoader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

        # Get one batch of Data
        # len(images): 32
        # len(labels): 32
        # shape of images[0]: torch.Size([3, 224, 224])
        images, labels = next(iter(dataLoader))

        # img.shape: [224,224,3]
        img = images[0].numpy().reshape([224, 224, 3])

        plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()
```

I expect the image to be a single RGB image of a dog or a cat. But the output I am getting is the plot of R,G,B components of that image as columns in a single plot as shown below.
[image]

Comment: *You* have reshaped the image to (224,224,3). What's its original shape?

Comment: Hi. The original shape was (3, 224, 224). I reshaped it for plotting purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code finally worked using np.transpose() function instead of the np.reshape() function.

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define Image Transform
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                                transforms.ToTensor()])

# Load Custom Image Dataset
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root="./Cat_Dog_data", transform=transform)

# DataLoader is a Generator
dataLoader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

# Get one batch of Data
images, labels = next(iter(dataLoader))

# Use transpose instead of reshape.
img = images[0].numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```